# No network adapters in windows 10 home build 15xx

Tags: windows-10, drivers, network-adapter, device-manager, netsh

Ethernet wired internet has always worked fine before, except for the wireless adapter, so I tried reinstalling the wifi adapter drivers, didn't work, then I tried a suggestion I read somewhere, which was in cmd "netcfg -d" and then reboot.

Upon reboot not only did the wireless interface still not appear, the lan interface was gone too, also 2 vmnet interfaces disappeared too (I have virtualbox installed), so it's just empty now,

When I do netsh wlan show interface it comes up empty also, adapters are empty, so I basically tried everything in this list: http://www.askvg.com/fix-network-connections-folder-is-empty-in-windows-not-showing-network-adapters-list/

Nothing worked, I still have network connections with a red cross in the right bottom, and it can still not see any network adapters, I have tried everything except for the "status -> reset network" since that's not yet available on this build, the option isn't there..
The crazy thing is that it does actually see all the adapters in device manager, and it has all the drivers installed, but in networkdevices it's all empty, I'm getting hopeless here

Ps. I did not upgrade it to windows 10, it was a fresh install about a year ago.
And it's also not the cabling, I just checked that with another device

Comment: Yea but i would rather avoid that, because last time i upgraded to the aniversary edition it messed up the oculus rift drivers making my screen go black, only option i had left then to get it working again was to revert to 1511.. So in that scenario I'm stuck inbetween 2 evils

Comment: Does it still give me the option to revert if something is wrong like it did with the aniversary update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an upgrade with an iso of the 1607 build I downloaded with another device, and it restored all internet connectivity and all adapters are showing up again, all the files and applications were kept intact also.